# How to link the external js file into reactjs app and make changes in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually, I have a header and on scrolled the icons and everything inside the header should change to black and headers background should be white.
By the way, I kind a know how to change the `bgcolor` on another path rather than home path.
And I also want to achieve those changing property by linking the external js file rather than inline style.

How to do that in react app?

Here is an example where to can demonstrate your idea. [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-wood-et1uk?file=/src/Dasa/Dasa.js)

**Basically I need two things**

1. When we go into the DASA page [Home Page](https://et1uk.csb.app/). When scrolled its `bgcolor` and text and icons color should change.
2. When we go to [signin page](https://et1uk.csb.app/signin) /SIGNIN  or click to `person icon`. In that page header's text and icons color should change without scrolling.

**How can I achieve all this using external js file?**

Answer (score 0):

For 1. you can check when user scroll by using this built-in function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo
so and run this in useEffect.
also you need to set bg color state default. so when you first render the component use that state bgcolor and then run useEffect when user scroll
something like this

```
useEffect(()=>{ setBgColor(red) }, [window.scrollTo(0, 0);])
```

For 2. use onClick handler person icon and use logic like

```
const onChangeColor = () => {
  if(math.route === singIn ) {
   setBgcolor(red)
}
}
<img personIcon onClick={onChanageColor} />
```

Comment: Is there any way I could do this using an external js file? Or I have to do this all in the same js file i.e. header.js.
Basically what I mean is, how to use an external js file for getting all the mentioned functionality?

Comment: only checking 2 logic in external js file it will add complexity